# Redirect while omiting a directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have searched and don't think my particular question has been answered.

I have the following code which works find as an `index.php` redirect to my main url and allows for a few scenarios

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

However, the problem is that my administration login is also at an index.php url which means it wont work while the above code is active. My admin is /admin. So I wondered if there was a way to tweak the above shown code to omit its behavior upon the admin directory in order for login to continue to work.

Or is there a better way to allow for both of the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the admin folder by prepending this this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^admin/
```

If I understand your scenario right, you want to redirect any index.php except the one in the `/admin/` folder, for that these rules should be sufficient:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Many thanks Mario.

I now have this code

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^admin/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]


Would it matter if I have already stepped down into the /admin directory?

website.co.uk/admin

Because I can't login while the code is active still.

Many thanks,

Al.

Comment: I don't think you need your second rule. I made an update of my anser.

Comment: Thanks Mario!! I tried that and it does seem to disable my admin login also. It throws me to this url /admin/?route=common/login. Any thoughts? If it helps this is an Open Cart login. Cheers, Al.

Comment: sorry, can't help you with that. this redirect seems to be caused by open cart itself and has nothing to do with the .htaccess rewrite rules

Comment: No problems Mario. Admin login does work fine when the code isnt active. Maybe it just cant be done... Cheers for your help. Al.